# Puting components using GridBagLayout on full screen

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

My problem is that I want to make more complicated (for me) graphical interface for my project. First of all I'm using full screen mode with the code below:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
...
private Container container;
private GridBagLayout gbl;

public MainFrame()
{
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice dev = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
dev.setFullScreenWindow(this);
setLayoutManager();
}
...
}
```

and everything is ok.
The next step I do is adding two JPanels. Layout manager that I want to use is GridBagLayout.

```
private void setLayoutManager()
{
container = getContentPane();
gbl = new GridBagLayout();
container.setLayout(gbl);
}

private void addMenu()
{
MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.ipady = 0;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 0.05;
gbl.setConstraints(menu, gbc);
container.add(menu);
}

private void addWorkArea()
{
WorkArea area = new WorkArea();
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbl.setConstraints(area, gbc);
container.add(area);
}
```

And the result looks like that:

[image]

Here is [my project](http://speedy.sh/vg9WB/Program.rar):

Why is there is a strip on the top?

What is more when I click there and drag, all application is moving. Please help me. It is important for me to fill all the space get rid of JFrame moving.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Consider using a nested layout. 3) Add a question mark to questions.

Comment: Try setting fullscreen after setting the layout. Also try setting the layout to the frame itself and not the contentpane

Comment: I know that answers that amount to "don't do that" are typically unwelcome, but...

GridBagLayout has to be the most difficult layout manager to understand / use. 

There are plenty of easier-to-use layout managers. 
Take a look at MigLayout, for instance. Or at least use nested BorderLayouts.

Comment: I second GreyBeardedGeek. [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is _much_ easier to work with than GridBagLayout. There's a great cheat sheet here: http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html

Comment: +1 for the complete source that compiled :D

Comment: Thanks for attention. Andrew Thompson I don't know the reason of  "Add a question mark to questions." Where should I add additional '?' ?
Of course I know gridBagLayout is one of the most difficult layouts. Thanks for suggestions of different layouts but I'll try to use GridBafLayut to gain some experience on that. If I couldn't cope with that I'll use other layouts.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to laugh when I tell you what the problem is...

Java, for what ever reason, is allowing for the frames insets when it's laying out the content.  That is, it still believes that there is a title bar and frame border.

The fix is horrendously complicated though...

In your `MainFrame` constructor, you need to call `setUndecorated(true)` before you do anything else...

```
public MainFrame() {
    setUndecorated(true); // <-- Add me
    setFullScreen();
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Program");
    setLayoutManager();
    addMenu();
    addWorkArea();
}
```

I know, horrendously complicated (insert sarcasm :P - seriously, I surprised myself when it worked)

Comment: You mean it is not fixed by a call to `pack()` or `validate()`?  BTW - Did you download the RAR?  Noticed your comment re. 'compilable'..

Comment: I think you meant that he needs to call `setUndecorated(true);` and not `setUndecorated(false);`...

Comment: @guillaumepolet, nope as stated, the frame needs to be undecorated so as to remove the phantom frame insets

Comment: @Andrew yep, downloaded the rar & tested directly against his code. Nice to have code that compiles & runs

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's exactly what I am saying but your answer is self-contradicting. In the text you state _you need to call setUndecorated(false) before..._ but in your code you call `setUndecorated(true);` Consider re-reading your answer.